# when using while loop in the progam, the application is not exiting

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

I have created an application in visual studio 2012 c++. The idea is to read the data from the serial port and to change the color for the label accordingly.I have used while loop to change the color in a continuous manner. Now, the application is working perfectly. The problem am facing is the application not existing when i click on the exit button or 'x' button in the application.I can able to close only in task manager by clicking on end task. The following is code of my application. Please let me know is there any way to fix this problem

```
 while(checkBox1->Checked)
         {
            if(this->serialPort1->IsOpen)
            {
                    int b[4] = {0};
                    int *ptr1;
                    ptr1 = b;
                    //this->serialPort1->DiscardInBuffer();
                    for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
                    {
                        *ptr1 = this->serialPort1->ReadChar();
                        ptr1++;
                    }
                    int address;
                    address = ((b[0]-48)*10)+(b[1]-48);
                    System::Windows::Forms::Label ^ ptr;

                    switch (address)
                    {
                        case 1: ptr = label1; 
                            break;
                        case 2: ptr = label2;
                            break;
                        case 3: ptr = label3;
                            break;
                        case 4: ptr = label4;
                            break;
                        case 5: ptr = label5;
                            break;
                        case 6: ptr = label6;
                            break;
                        case 7: ptr = label7;
                            break;
                        case 8: ptr = label8;
                            break;
                        default: //MessageBox::Show("Default Case");
                            break;
                    }
                    if(b[2]=='o')
                    {
                        ptr->BackColor = Color::Red;
                        ptr->Text="R";
                    }
                    else if(b[2]=='a')
                    {
                        ptr->Text=String::Empty;
                        ptr->BackColor = Color::Green;
                    }
                    else if(b[2]=='i')
                    {
                        ptr->Text=String::Empty;
                        ptr->BackColor = Color::Blue;
                    }
                    if ((b[3]-48)<3)
                    {
                        ptr->Text=String::Empty;
                        ptr->BackColor = Color::SaddleBrown;
                        //_sleep(5000);
                    }
```

Comment: Did you specify a read timeout? Or is the timeout still set to the default `InfiniteTimeout`? If infinite i believe that the program hangs in the blocking `ReadChar()` function. See [SerialPort.ReadTimeout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  for more info.

Comment: there is no time out. But if there is a problem is with ReadChar(), the application will not work right? The application can change the label color by reading the serial data

Comment: There is no problem with `ReadChar`, but without timeout `ReadChar` blocks until a character is available, which makes it difficult to close the app without killing it. But with debugging or logging it should be no problem to find out whether the program hangs in `ReadChar` or if it does not.

Comment: I don't have problem in reading the data from serial port. When i click on the check box, it should read the data from the serial port and color should change. When i un check the check box, it should stop reading the data. Now, the problem is I cant able to un check the checkbox and operate any controls buttons in the application.

Comment: I don't have problem in reading the data from serial port. When i click on the check box, it should read the data from the serial port and color should change. When i un check the check box, it should stop reading the data. Now, the problem is I cant able to un check the checkbox and operate any controls buttons in the application.

Comment: If `checkBox1->Checked` and `serialPort1->IsOpen` are both true, the inner part of the `while` loop is being executed again and again. That means, that any available characters are being read from the serial port (step by step), including some color changes. If no more data is available on the port `ReadChar()`is being called again nevertheless. And this function blocks. Who should end it? Due to this the `while` condition will not be evaluated again. You'll at least need a timeout handling (and you should execute the serial communication from a different thread or as overlapped IO).

Comment: Alternatively you can check if there's some data available on the port using [SerialPort.BytesToRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.bytestoread(v=vs.110).aspx) Property (which is non blocking) and to call `ReadChar()` only if data is available, otherwise sleep a litle time (e.g. one second),

Comment: ya its correct but serial data is a continuous stream of data receiving from a embedded device, i don't want to stop reading it. As long as the check box is checked it should read data. When i un check, the data read must stop. When i again check it, it should start reading.

Answer (score 2):

If you do UI programming, you must use an event driven mechanism! In your case, you should register to the "[DataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived)" event in order to get called if new data arrives from the port.

```
private: System::Void serialPort1_DataReceived(System::Object^  sender, System::IO::Ports::SerialDataReceivedEventArgs^  e)
{
    array<unsigned char> ^data = gcnew array<unsigned char>(4);
    serialPort1->Read(data, 0, 4);
    // Do whatever you want...
}
```

In the event handler "checkBox1_CheckedChanged" you should just open or close the serial port!

```
private: System::Void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
  if (checkBox1->Checked)
  {
      serialPort1->Open();
  }
  else
  {
      serialPort1->Close();
  }
}
```

Also I suggest to set the "read theresehold" to 4...

```
serialPort1->ReceivedBytesThreshold = 4;
```